# Google maps apikey doubts

Tags: google-maps, geometry, api-key, billing

I have been reading about Google apikey but I steel have doubts, I’m writing a program where I need to use Google maps and specifically geometry library, I’m going to sell this program. The user not going to use the program so much (just 10 request maximum “thinking about usage limits”), and the program is not for a web, is just intranet! So the doubt is: does I really need to have an apikey? And if so… what I need to do?

If you know how I can communicate with Google people, I will appreciate!
or if you know how to replace the google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation method....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an API key and for commercial software you are subject to restriction according to GoogleMaps policy rule:

[Can I use the Google Maps API on a commercial website?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial)

Comment: Ok but that means they don’t going to charge me for the key, it is just if I exceed the limits right?....I mean I can get it for free..

Comment: Absolutely yes, this means.

Comment: This are the usage limits https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage